# Nikon P7100 doesn't connect as a mass storage device

Tags: usb-drive, camera, mass-storage

I've tried connecting a Nikon P7100 camera to a USB-port on two different laptops running Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04 but nothing happens. The camera says it's got MTP/PTP protocol. So it doesn't work as a mass storage device it seems. I can find no setting for changing the mode in the camera.

lsusb gives:
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04b0:018b Nikon Corp.

Is it possible to mount this camera somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Using `Usb_modeswitch` as discussed above **won't** work, but there are some alternative ways of accessing your photos , at least one of which should work for you:

On some cameras (like my friend's Nikon D70) there is an option on the camera that allows you to connect it to the computer as a mass storage device. However, on your P7100 I don't think there is that option after looking through the specs listed at [the official site](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/coolpix/performance/p7100/spec.htm) and studying the [manual](http://nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/kie88335f7869dfuejdl=-cww2/P7100EN.pdf).

**However**, there is one option that might work for you; as you know your camera is a `MTP` device you could try mounting it manually with `gvfs-mount` and the gphoto2 protocol which has support for `MTP` devices. All you need to do is find (as you have done already) the usb bus location of your camera (i.e. the two numbers: Bus 002, Device 007), although that will probably change every time you connect your camera, so remember to check with `lsusb`. Enter, for example:

```
gvfs-mount gphoto2://[usb:002,007]
```

Then the camera should be available for you to import pictures via applications like `gthumb`, or at the very least you will be able to browse the `.gvfs` folder where it is mounted (enable hidden files in your file browser to see the `.gvfs` folder).

For Ubuntu 12.10 and later: the `~/.gvfs` folder is now at `/run/user/username/gvfs`.

If the mount does not succeed, you could obviously take the memory card out and place it in a card-reader, but  perhaps that is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last several lines of the output of the `dmesg` command 10 seconds after you connect the camera. It should show something. Also try `df -h` to see if it's mounted.

Try `usb_modeswitch`. Read `man usb__modeswitch`. If you don't have `usb_modeswitch`, it can be installed via `sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch{,-data}`.
**Note:** The program name is `usb`**_**`modeswitch`, but the package name is `usb`**-**`modeswitch`.

`man usb_modeswitch` says, in part:

```
   On  Linux,  in  most  cases  the drivers are provided as a Linux kernel
   module, such as "usbserial". However, the  device  shows  up  as  "usb-
   storage"  by  default.  usb-modeswitch solves that issue by sending the
   respective command which actually performs the switching of the  device
   from "usb-storage" to the target mode like "usbserial".
```

But then I read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol (after Googling "MTP"), which listed several Linux apps that supported MTP/PTP.