# Mounting a camera as mass storage automatically

Tags: usb, mount, camera, thunar, gvfs

When I connect the camera via the USB cable, its is detected by `lsusb` but it's not mounted. I followed the answer to this question: [Nikon P7100 doesn't connect as a mass storage device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89629/nikon-p7100-doesnt-connect-as-a-mass-storage-device)
 Now it doesn't show in Thunar's "Devices" menu but `gthumb` can show the files on the device. It doesn't show up in the `gvfs` folder either. Is there any way to have it mount automatically?

Comment: Your question implies that you've been able to mount it as USB Mass Storage manually, but not automatically, but I don't know how as I don't think it's capable of that.  I think it's MTP/PTP only.  Can you confirm whether it's USB Mass Storage capable?

Comment: Actually, your question doesn't make it clear whether your camera is a Nikon P7100 too - is it?

Comment: I don't know if its MTP capable. On Windows it didn't mount until I installed a prorietary Nikon software. Not just the mount is not automatic, I don't know were gvfs mounts it. As I said Gthumb can access it after mount but not Thunar.

Comment: PTP/MTP and USB Mass Storage are two different and incompatible protocols.  I take it that you were intending just to ask how to mount it, in general, by whatever means?

Comment: What camera do you have?  Is it the Nikon P7100?

Comment: Yes, by any means.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera does not support being mounted as a USB Mass Storage device, however it does support MTP/PTP.

This will allow it to show up in gthumb and other image viewers or camera import tools that use gphoto2.

It will also allow it to appear by default in Nautilus, but it sounds like Thunar does not include support for MTP devices by default.

According to [this discussion](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=36332), you will need to install the package `gvfs-backends` (which you may already have).  That will install the ability to mount MTP devices on the filesystem but it doesn't magically teach Thunar how to mount/unmount them.

For that you'll need some other tool to mount/unmount them, and apparently people have had success with `gmtp`.  An alternative was `go-mtpfs` but someone said that didn't work out.

If this is too difficult you could just install `nautilus` and use that instead of Thunar when you want to access the contents of MTP devices.

Comment: gmtp doesn't work. I believe Thunar does support MTP because I can access my cellphone using Thunar.