# Can't detect my USB camera connection

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, camera

It's really strange because on my previous installs on the same PC, of Ubuntu 16.04, as soon as I connected the camera, it was detected. Very quickly in fact.

On my latest install of this OS though, nothing.
Here's the output from the `lusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b0:017e Nikon Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

As you can see the camera is there. But it's simply missing from File explorer.

Comment: AFAIK in order to appear in the file explorer, a camera needs to be recognized as an *storage device* rather than a generic USB device: see for example [Nikon P7100 doesn't connect as a mass storage device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89629/nikon-p7100-doesnt-connect-as-a-mass-storage-device)

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the 'gphoto2' to see if the camera is supported. See if is recognized at all try:

`gphoto2 --auto-detect`

More specifics on camera model would help. 04b0:017e Doesn't seem to bring anything up for that usb device id.